# Proof the following: If $n \in \mathbb N$ and $2^n+1$ is a prime, then $n$ has the form $2^r, r \in \mathbb N_0$.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

This problem was divided by the instructor in three parts. The problem in the title is the last part.

**Part 1:** Prove the following equivalence about a natural number $n>1$
"$n$ can be written as a power of 2 iff $n$ does not have other odd divisors than $\pm 1$"

This I have proven using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

**Part 2:** Let $n=km, \quad k,m \in \mathbb N$ and $m$ is odd. Show by calculation the following and consider why m is odd
$\left(2^{k}+1\right)\left(2^{k m-k}-2^{k m-2 k}+2^{k m-3 k}-2^{k m-4 k}+\cdots+1\right)=\left(2^{k m}+1\right)$

I have also done that.

**Part 3:** Prove, If $n \in \mathbb N$ and $2^n+1$ is a prime, then $n$ has the form $2^r, r \in \mathbb N_0$. *I'm stuck here!*

A hint is given: see the proof of the following theorem: 
$\forall n \in \mathbb N$, if $2^n-1$ is prime, then $n$ is prime.
I understand the proof but apparently not adequately to prove part 3.

Comment: The last part is simply a proof by contradiction : If no odd prime factors are possible , we must have a power of $2$ (because if we assume that $n$ is NOT a power of $2$, it must have an odd prime factor) .I added the complete proof (including the three steps indirectly) below.

Comment: By the way, primes of the form $$2^{2^m}+1$$ are called Fermat-primes, for $m\le 4$, all those numbers are prime and there seems to be no prime for $m>4$

Comment: Edit: I forgot the word "odd". I have edited.

Comment: I just noticed and hence deleted my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose, $\ m\ $ is an odd prime factor of $\ n\ $. Then, there exists a positive integer $\ k\ $ with $\ k\cdot m= n\ $. With $\ N:=2^k+1\ $ we have $$2^n=2^{k\cdot m}=(2^k)^m\equiv (-1)^m=-1\mod N$$ hence $\ N\ $ is a non-trivial factor of $\ 2^n+1\ $ because $\ n=k\ $ would imply $\ m=1\ $

Hence if $\ 2^n+1\ $ is prime, $\ n\ $ must be a power of $\ 2\ $.

Comment: Thank you. I will need some time to understand this. I will be back for questions if it's OK with you.

Comment: no problem, just ask later

Comment: I'm finally almost done. I have done it a tiny bit different than your proof. I have not used modular arithmetic. The only thing I need to show that the factor $\left(2^{k m-k}-2^{k m-2 k}+2^{k m-3 k}-2^{k m-4 k}+\cdots+1\right)$ from part 2 is between 1 and $\left(2^{k m}+1\right)$. My plan was to write the factor  as something very compact so it would be easier to compare it with 1 and $\left(2^{k m}+1\right)$. I failed. If you don't mind. Do you have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Why not use the factor $2^k+1$ ? This is clearly a nontrivial factor , if $m>1$ holds. It is then obvious that the cofactor (the other factor) is a nontrivial factor as well.

Comment: I see this point. But I have to show it. My experience (from other assigments) tell me that I also should explain that $1< \left(2^{k m-k}-2^{k m-2 k}+2^{k m-3 k}-2^{k m-4 k}+\cdots+1\right) < \left(2^{k m}+1\right)$ and $1 < 2^k+1 < 2^{km}+1$.

Comment: Although this is not necessary, this can be done : In the alternating sum , every positive number is larger (in absolute value) than the following negative number, hence $1<...$ can easily be done. If you omit the first number, every negative number is larger (in absolute value) than the following positive number, hence the sum must be smaller than the first term which is enough to complete. But if we have $n=ab$ with $1<a<n$, then $1<b<n$ follows immediately (if $n,a,b$ are positive integers). Hence you need not make life harder than it is.

Comment: Thanks, got it.